# Floyd–Warshall algorithm with path reconstruction does not find a path

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I am trying to find a shortest path between a source and a target using Floyd-Warshall's algorithm by computing the shortest paths between all pairs.

I need to find the shortest **path** not just the distance. This is what I'm trying to do:

I store the first vertex on the shortest path from i to j. Whenever the shortest path from i to j is updated and it now goes through k, I set the first vertex on the shortest path from i to j to that on the shortest path from i to k.

```
/*first[i][j] is the first vertex after i on the shortest path from i to j.
first[i][j] is initially j if there is an edge from i to j and the dist[i][j] is the weight of the edge. Otherwise f[i][j] is -1 and the cost is infinity.
*/
for(k = 0; k < N; ++k){
    for(i = 0; i  < N; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j){
            if(dist[i][j] >= dist[i][k]+dist[k][j]){
               dist[i][j] = dist[i][k]+dist[k][j];
               //When the distance is updated, update first[i][j]
               first[i][j] = first[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this algorithm is that when I run this algorithm on the following graph, the path found by this algorithm is an infinite cycle.

[image: the graph]

Here is the `first` matrix computed by the algorithm:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 
2 2 2 2 2 2 
5 5 5 5 5 5 
1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
2 2 2 2 2 2
```

The first vertex on the shortest path from 0 to any other vertex, according to the algorithm is 4, but the first vertex on the shortest path from 4 to any other vertex is 0.

- Why does this algorithm behave in this manner ?
- Is there a another way to compute the first (after the source) vertex on every path **while I am computing the length of the path**?

I have read the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) article and also some questions on SO but they weren't of much help.

Comment: Are dist and first initialized properly? BTW, I'd recommend python for experimenting around with algorithms. Much easier.

Comment: Yes they are initialized properly, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: 'otherwise it is -1'. There you have your issue. A cost of -1 is always the cheapest.

Comment: Not the cost, first[i][j] is -1. The problem, I think, is not with the code, but with the algorithm

Comment: Whoops... I see you clarified it again :)

Comment: @mic_e it is Infinity, a big number.

Comment: Aaaand... the graph is unclear: Is the edge between 0 and 3 unidirectional? And one more unclear thing: Is `dist[i][i]` 0?

Comment: No it goes to 3, I'll clarify that. Thanks

Comment: Note that in wikipedia, the comparision is not `>=`, but `>`. Writing `>=` in that place _might_ be the cause of your self-loops.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dist` matrix already seems to be calculated correctly, but your `first` matrix additions seem to have a problem with zero-cost edges.

See this slightly modified python version of your code, which uses `0.01` as cost for all self-edges and other 0-cost edges.

http://pastebin.com/fub60HA5

That code outputs the (hopefully) correct `dist` and `first` matrices

```
[0.01,  inf,  inf, 0.01, 0.01,  inf]
[0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0.02]
[0.01,  inf, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01]
[ inf,  inf,  inf, 0.01,  inf,  inf]
[0.01,  inf,  inf, 0.02, 0.01,  inf]
[0.02,  inf, 0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01]
```

and

```
[   0, None, None,    3,    4, None]
[   2,    1,    2,    3,    2,    2]
[   0, None,    2,    5,    0,    5]
[None, None, None,    3, None, None]
[   0, None, None,    0,    4, None]
[   2, None,    2,    3,    2,    5]
```

Comment: Thanks. And you were right about the >= too, because then first[i][j] will be set only once for the shortest path and it will be correct.